# ViewController's view not showing in NSBox with cocoa Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbox

I'm pretty new to cocoa for Mac development. I'm currently struggling with getting a viewController's view to show up as a NSBox's contentView. The relevant code looks like this:

```
// AccountsViewController.h. ManagingViewController is a custom subclass of NSViewController
// as of Cocoa Programming for Mac.
@interface AccountsViewController : ManagingViewController
{
    LoginViewController *loginViewController;
}

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSBox *box; 

// Implementation

@implementation AccountsViewController
@synthesize box;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.

        // Should display the view in the contentView(!?!)
        loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        box.contentView = loginViewController.view;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Currently, nothing displays in the box's contentView. What should I do to get the viewControllers view into the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that init is too early to be adding/changing views. Implement an [awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method on the AccountsViewController and set the content view there. awakeFromNib will be called on your class after the nib is loaded and everything is ready to be manipulated.